# Как исправить зависание Pull To Refresh в iOS?

Tags: ios, swift3, pulltorefresh

Имплементировал `Pull To Refresh` в приложение. Сначла работало все хорошо. На этой неделе начало зависать.
Когда потянуть вниз, перезагрузка работает прекрасно. Но "потянутый" экран замораживаться внизу и висит пока его снова не передвинуть пальцем. Это напрягает при использовании и выглядит непроффесионально.
От чего это может зависеть? Так как эта фунция запрограммированная apple, то мне не приходит в голову как мой код мог на это повлиять.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте код что и как делаете или новый проект где воспроизводится эта ошибка.

Comment: ну да не понятно!